# gradle placeholder can not solve the ${com.nssb.zssb}

Tags: android, gradle, placeholder

gradle placeholder support problem :

my placeholder looks like ${com.nssb.zssb}

how can gradle deal with this situation, I tried the following command:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [com.nssb.zssb:"djdssb"]
```

but it didnt worked. any suggestion?  many thanks~~~~~

my mainifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="differentbuild.com.mike.differentbuild" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="${com.nssb.zssb}"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="${com.nssb.zssb}" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="${com.nssb.zssb}" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "differentbuild.com.mike.differentbuild"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

    productFlavors {
        production {
            applicationId "differentbuild.com.mike.differentbuild"
            manifestPlaceholders = [com.nssb.zssb:"SecondActivity"]
            versionName "1.0-pro"

        }
        pros {
            applicationId "differentbuild.com.mike.differentbuild"
            manifestPlaceholders = [com.nssb.zssb:"SecondActivity111"]
            versionName "1.0.1-pro"

        }

    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Comment: post more code. `${com.nssb.zssb}` references variable, while in your example `com.nssb.zssb` is map key.

Comment: @nikis thank for your answer I have post more code, if I change placeholder from ${com.nssb.zssb} to ${nssb} it works fine.

Comment: just add quotes around keys in your gradle file, like so 'com.nssb.zssb'

Comment: @nikis haha!!  thank you very  very much, love you :) because of you I can go home earlier !